# Issue with div shadow and Z-index

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am creating a page what will be loaded into another page via ajax. It has a top bar and a table below it that is located inside a jquery scrollbar plugin.

The problem I seem to be having is that the *top bar* has a shadow below it that you can only see when the below table is scrolled over the white rows (which are white because they have no background).

[Here is the demo in question](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table/all-events.html) (best to inspect with firebug)

I tried setting the z-index of the top bar without luck.
I also tried setting the z-index of the jquery scrollbar div - **which worked**, but it broke the ability to click the table rows.

I made a little image of what I'm talking about :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set top bar's z-index without setting it's position to relative or absolute first. Applied "position: relative;" to #content-placeholder fixed it to me.

Comment: You are the best! It says I can award the bounty in 19 hours but you earned it :))

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in firebug.

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #BABABA;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did help me with the sorter, however many functions stop working when the topbar shadow is implemented. I will try other ways of doing this. Thanks :)

Comment: The functions probably stopped working because "z-index: -1;" moved them below table, so then you clicked them you just clicked blank space above the actual content. It's not shadow's fault.